# What are alternative IDEs to ADT eclipse ? the emulator in adt eclipse is VERY SLOW

Tags: android-emulator

I tried to develop apps in standard ADT - but it is very slow to respond to my clicks on the virtual smartphone..

Are there other FASTER alternative IDEs to ADT and better simulator coming with it?

Comment: The emulator is part of the developer tools, not the IDE, so switching to another IDE will leave you with the same emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Use [BlueStack App Player](http://www.bluestacks.com/) Its extremely fast and easy to use with eclipse. In order to use it with eclipse, just open the command prompt and type

```
adb connect 127.0.0.1
```

then you can launch your apks on it and it will run without any hassle.

Find the detailed tutorial [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1303563)